# Vimdiff bad line alignment and subsequent diff visualization

Tags: syntax-highlighting, vimdiff

Let's say I have two files with the following contents:

```
this is some important text
another different line
if another is needed
here it is
```

and

```
this is some important text
we now first add two new lines
in place of the old second
if another is sorely needed
here it is
```

Now it should be visible that the second file has substituted the second line in the first file with two new lines, and it has a minor edit on the third line (`sorely`). My problem is that when `vimdiff`ing these files, the result is quite suboptimal:

[image: erroneous vimdiff]

`vimdiff` reports the second and third line in both files as completely changed, and a whole new line added in the second file. Instead, I'd have preferred to see the second line in file 1 marked as deleted, and its 3rd line marked as edited. Is there a way to make `vimdiff` do so?

I'm using vim 9.0, and my current `diffopt` is

```
internal,filler,closeoff,algorithm:histogram,indent-heuristic,vertical
```

Comment: Welcome to Vi and Vim SE. Note that diff tools run on *lines*. What you see is just surprising syntax highlighting. I added the respective tag. I hope this will help our highlight-savvy contributors to find an answer.

Comment: And another note: you don't show your `diffopt` but what you *add* to it. Use `:set diffopt?` to show the value. As this question is about highlighting, the option's value doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: @Friedrich Is it really only about syntax highlighting? The way the lines are compared and matched surely is influenced by the diff algorithm and related options, no? The diff shown here is not *wrong*, per se, it's just that it's not a good one, which would result by realizing that the second line on the left side is what has been deleted and matching the third line with its edited counterpart.

Comment: I do think so but I could be wrong. I ran your example through (among other things) GNU `diff` and `git diff --no-index`, both with and without the `--minimal` option. Result is always the same: +3 lines -2 lines, as above. I'd think the highlighting is applied on the line level.

Answer (score 1):

The classic diff algorithm focuses on line comparison and produced diff that group equal lines and not lines that are similar. This lead to the line de-synchronization you observe.

I have tested the various builtin algorithm of Vim and it seems that none of them provide the comparison you need.

Vim supports the `diffexpr` option that let you specify the logic (VimScript function) that compare the files.

More information in [:help diff-diffexpr](https://vimhelp.org/diff.txt.html#diff-diffexpr)

The `git-diff` algorithm is able to compare within the line and group similar lines together using the `--word-diff` option:

```
git-diff --word-diff file1.txt file2.txt
```

Remark: The output syntax of `git-diff` is not the one expected by Vim. A conversion within the `diffexpr` would be needed.

Update:

- I confirmed that the unified format `-U0` is supported by Vim
- A @Brabant says Vim perform twice the comparison

  - The first time with two simple files (whose content are respectively `line1` and `line2`) to check the diff
  - The second time with the content of the buffers
- I have tried to post process the unified format to add synchronization block to help Vim to identify modification inline but that doesn't seems to work.

Here is my try:

```
set diffexpr=MyDiff()

function MyDiff()
  let prediff = tempname()

  let command = '!git diff --word-diff=plain -U0 ' .. v:fname_in .. ' ' .. v:fname_new .. ' --output ' .. prediff
  silent execute command

  let command = '!post.py --input ' .. prediff .. ' --output ' .. v:fname_out .. ''
  silent execute command

  redraw!
endfunction
```

Where the `post.py` that post-process the unified diff file is:

```python
import sys
import argparse
import datetime
import logging
import os
import re


class Sync:
    def __init__(self):
        self.context = ""
        self.apos = 0
        self.bpos = 0

        self.alen = 0
        self.blen = 0

        self.lines = []

    def print(self, g):
        # if not g:
        #     g = sys.stdout

        g.write(f"@@ -{self.apos},{self.alen} +{self.bpos},{self.blen} @@ {self.context}\n")
        for line in self.lines:
            g.write(line + "\n")

def post(args):
    in_path = args.input
    out_path = args.output
    if out_path:
        g = open(out_path, mode="wt")
    else:
        g = sys.stdout

    with open(in_path, mode="rt") as f:
        sync = None
        acur = 0
        bcur = 0
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip("\r\n")
            m = re.match(r'^@@ -(\d*),(\d+) \+(\d*),(\d+) @@ (.*)', line)
            if m:
                if sync:
                    sync.print(g)

                sync = Sync()
                sync.apos = int(m.group(1))
                sync.bpos = int(m.group(3))
                sync.context = m.group(5)

                acur = sync.apos
                bcur = sync.bpos
                continue

            if not sync:
                # print the header
                g.write(line + "\n")
                continue

            new_sync = True
            if line.startswith('[-'):
                new_sync = False
                acur += 1
                sync.alen += 1

            if line.endswith('+}'):
                new_sync = False
                bcur += 1
                sync.blen += 1

            if acur == bcur:
                new_sync = False

            if not new_sync:
                sync.lines.append(line)
                continue

            sync.print(g)
            sync = Sync()
            sync.apos = acur
            sync.bpos = bcur
            sync.lines.append(line)
            sync.alen += 1
            sync.blen += 1

    if sync:
        sync.print(g)


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--input", action="store", help="Input", default="")
    parser.add_argument("--output", action="store", help="Output", default="")

    try:
        args = parser.parse_args()

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(str(e))
        return

    post(args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It seems that `--word-diff=porcelain` does output a format that vim can read, but even after trying it the displayed output is the same. I've set `diffexpr` to a function that calls `silent execute "!git diff --no-index -U0 --word-diff=porcelain " .. v:fname_in .. " " .. v:fname_new .. " > " .. v:fname_out`

Comment: @Svalorzen if that fixes your issue, feel free to post an answer of your own. Self-answers are encouraged. Your code will also be much more readable.

Comment: @Friedrich I have mentioned that the displayed output is the same, i.e. the problem is not fixed, although I guess now I can make vim use git-diff as the diff source.

Comment: I have tried myself and what I observe on Windows looks odd. The content of `v:fname_in` is `line1` and `f:name_new` is `line2` whatever the file I compare. Do you experience the same? What is the operating system you are using?

Comment: that is expected output. Vim will always first test the `diff` output with dummy input `line1` and `line2`

Comment: BTW: `word-diff` is not supported by Vim at all

Comment: That is fine by me; I'd just really like vim to match the edited line of the two files. This happens if I for example introduce an empty line in the first file (say as second line). Then the edited line is correctly matched and the diff looks good. But with the original files, this does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

How would you like to try [spotdiff.vim](https://github.com/rickhowe/spotdiff.vim) plugin? You can select area to compare partially. Here is your example.

[image]

As a side note, you can improve the vimdiff as word or character level with [diffchar.vim](https://github.com/rickhowe/diffchar.vim) plugin.

Comment: Interesting I just [recommended](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/43905/23502) your [spotdiff](https://github.com/rickhowe/spotdiff.vim) plugin :-). Nice to see you here. Thanks for your nice diff plugins!

Comment: Looks cool thanks! In my case unfortunately the problem happened within a larger diff when using fugitive's `:Gdiffsplit`, so I don't think this would fix my issue in general, but it's good to know about :)