# How can I sync cursor movement in two vertical windows of the same file?

Tags: cursor-motions, split

I can vertically split windows for the current file by `:vs`. Is there any way that I can sync cursor movement in the two windows? E.g. if the cursor in the left window moves up two lines, I want the cursor in the right window moves up two lines as well, **regardless which lines the cursors were before the movement**.

I've tried `cursorbind` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737398/how-to-synchronize-cursor-movement-in-multiple-split-windows), but it just change the cursor to the same position in the two windows. I also type `:set scrollbind` in the two windows, but but it only works when the cursor is on the top/bottom of the screen and it's a bit inconvenient. I wonder if there is a better solution.

---

update 1

The original problem is that I have a `Python` program like this and the output is redirected to a file:

```
for dataframeVariable in listDataframeVariable: # list length is 10
  print(dataframeVariable)
  dataframeVariable.make_changes()
  print(dataframeVariable)
```

I'd like to visually compare the content of the two prints. I know one workarond is to write a MACRO to move every second print to the end of the file, and move the appending content to another file, and use `vimdiff` to compare.

Do we have a better solution?

Comment: At first it seems not possible in Vim standard. Maybe if you give more information about why you want to have that someone can propose a solution to your original problem.

Comment: Agreeing with Vivian. A minimal example might help people understand what you're looking for.

Comment: There is only one cursor, the one in the current window, so binding two cursors in two windows is an ontological impossibility. Moreover, `scrollbind` only requires the cursor to be at the top/bottom of the screen if you incorrectly use `jk` or the arrows for scrolling. *Actual* scrolling commands like `<C-e>` or `<C-y>` allow the bound windows to scroll in sync, wherever the cursor is in either window.

Comment: A possible workaround to make "incorrect scrolling" work may be to force the cursor to the center line through `:set scrolloff=999` as suggested in `:help 'scrolloff'`.

Comment: I understand your original question, and I understand the actual problem you're trying to solve, but I don't understand how answering the question would solve your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be interested by the following [spotdiff](https://github.com/rickhowe/spotdiff.vim) plugin.

It allows you to select a range in one window and a range in another window and ask Vim to compare both.

Select the first spot and run `:Diffthis`
[image]

Select the second spot and run `:Diffthis`
[image]

A temporary buffer is created
I have moved aside using <kbd>Ctrl w</kbd>`L`
[image]

When your are done run `:Diffoff`
[image]

[image]

Comment: See also: https://github.com/AndrewRadev/linediff.vim